# How to display the List of object to view

Tags: c#, html

### My Model Class

```
 public class DisplaceModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Rating { get; set; }
        public string PhotoReference { get; set; }
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }
    }

public class DisplaceModelInformation
    {
        public List<DisplaceModel> Dispaylist { get; set; }
        public DisplaceModelInformation()
        {
            Dispaylist = new List<DisplaceModel>();
        }
     }
```

### And My Controller

```
var Display = new DisplaceModelInformation();
            XElement generalElement = xdoc1.Element("PlaceSearchResponse");
            Display.Dispaylist = (from c in xdoc1.Descendants("result")
                       select new DisplaceModel()
                        {
                            Name = Convert.ToString(c.Element("name").Value),
                            Address = Convert.ToString(c.Element("vicinity").Value),
                            Type = keyword,
                            Rating = (c.Element("rating") != null  ? Convert.ToString(c.Element("rating").Value) :null),
                            PhotoReference = (c.Element("photo") != null ? Convert.ToString(c.Element("photo").Element("photo_reference").Value) : null),
                            Width = (c.Element("photo") != null ? Convert.ToInt16(c.Element("photo").Element("width").Value) : 0),
                            Height = (c.Element("photo") != null ? Convert.ToInt16(c.Element("photo").Element("height").Value) : 0)
                        }).ToList<DisplaceModel>();

            return View(Display);
```

Now I try to display my list of object to view, I tried but I really dont know how to display in mvc view(cshtml) file

### My MVC View

```
@model IEnumerable<FindLocation.Models.DisplaceModelInformation>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>ADDRESS</th>
                <th>RATING</th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var element in Model)
            {
                if (element.Dispaylist.Count > 0 )
            {
                <tr>
                    <@*td>@element.Dispaylist from c </td>
                    <td>@Display.Address</td>
                    <td>@Display.Rating</td>*@
                </tr>
            }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I am new to UI  and I try to extract the list of object but i dont know how to list the object. so please help me....and thanks for your help

Comment: Use `@foreach (var element in Model.Dispaylist)`

Comment: i try this before it show as error IEnumerable<FindLocation.Models.DisplaceModelInformation> does not contain a definition for Dispaylist

Comment: Yes that error is correct. You need to change your model to `@model FindLocation.Models.DisplaceModelInformation` because you are passing `Display` to the view in your controller which is of type `DisplaceModelInformation` not  `IEnumerable<FindLocation.Models.DisplaceModelInformation>`

Comment: Thanks Yoshi its working could u please explain me why we are not use IEnumerable<FindLocation.Models.DisplaceModelInformation> where we have to use IEnumerable

Comment: Because you are only passing one `DisplaceModelInformation` from the controller to the view. In the view you are enumerating the `Dispaylist` property of `DisplaceModelInformation`.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the trouble might be coming from the type difference between what you're passing to the view from the controller (`DisplaceModelInformation`) and the `@model` definition in the view itself (`IEnumerable<DisplaceModelInformation>`). Changing one to match the other should help.

I think you have the right idea with `@foreach`. If your model is an `IEnumerable`, you would need to iterate over that collection first, then iterate over the `DisplayList` collection in another inner loop.

The answers to the following question seem to have some good examples of what you're trying to accomplish:
[Foreach in a Foreach in MVC View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973434/foreach-in-a-foreach-in-mvc-view)

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code:

1. In your Controller, you need to `return View(new List<DisplaceModelInformation> { Display });`, because you specified an IEnumerable model in your View: `@model IEnumerable<FindLocation.Models.DisplaceModelInformation>`
2. Use `foreach` to display each table row:

   ```
   @foreach (var element in Model)
   {
    if (element.Dispaylist.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var Display in element.Dispaylist)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Display.Name</td>
                <td>@Display.Address</td>
                <td>@Display.Rating</td>
            </tr>
        }
     }
   }
   ```